# Retrieve parameters from coroutine created with asyncio.as_completed

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am trying to execute IO-heavy tasks in a concurrent manner like so:

```
import asyncio


async def io_operation(param: int):
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    return param ** 2


async def main():
    io_calls = [io_operation(i) for i in range(10)]

    for i in asyncio.as_completed(io_calls):
        result = await i
        print(result)  # should also return the corresponding call parameters


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Now, as I cannot know in advance which order the results are going to be in, I would like to retrieve information about the call parameters of a coroutine returned by `asyncio.as_completed`. Is there a way to do this that does not require returning the parameters in the function `io_operation()`?

**Edit:** I send HTTP requests with different parameters to a website using `aiohttp`. Afterwards, I need to map the results to the original requests.

Comment: Do you need to work on the results as soon as they arrive, or is it ok to wait until everything is done?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [asyncio.gather](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather) to preserve the order:

```
import asyncio


async def io_operation(param: int):
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    return param ** 2


async def main():
    r = range(10)
    io_calls = [io_operation(i) for i in r]

    for param, result in zip(r, await asyncio.gather(*io_calls)):
        print(param, result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

But if you need the results as soon as they are ready just simply return the `param`:

```
import asyncio


async def io_operation(param: int):
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    return (param, param ** 2)


async def main():
    io_calls = [io_operation(i) for i in range(10)]

    for i in asyncio.as_completed(io_calls):
        param, result = await i
        print(param, result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: This appears to be the correct answer. However, returning the parameters does not feel very pythonic. Additionally, this works in my case, but what happens if `io_operation` was some library code I do not have control over?

Comment: So why do you want to return them in the first place? Is this some real problem you’re trying to solve?

Comment: I added a use case to my question.

Comment: Do you actually mean function params or URL params from the query string? I feel like we're missing the context here and there may be a better solution for your problem but without a proper example it'll be difficult to help. Your "worker" coroutine, that receives the params, should return the data already formatted or use `asyncio.gather` so you can map params and results in the `main` function. You could also implement a queue.